# Removing unwanted files from Windows Folder

Tags: windows, uninstall

Some software when installed puts some files in the Windows folder (or directory). This sometimes results in losing a large amount of disk space. How do I manually remove those files that don't get deleted even if you run the un-intsaller? Is there any software which cleans the Windows folder from unwanted files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well about how much disk space are we talking? If a program installs some DLLs you might never use again, that won't cause any trouble.

I personally would refrain from using any program that deletes something in the Windows folder. Unless you are 100% sure what you are deleting, I just wouldn't do it.

Apart from that, [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/) is a decent tool!

Answer (score 0):

The software that I use to keep my PC clean from junk is: [Advanced System Care](http://www.iobit.com/advancedwindowscareper.html), and [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/)  With the Advanced system care there is a third party uninstaller than may take care of those "lose" files.  Give them a shot and see what you think.